# proving logical explosion

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

i have a simple question: assume i have something like ($\Gamma \cup \{\delta \} \models \lnot \gamma$) AND ($\Gamma \cup \{\delta\} \models \gamma$). How may I show that $\Gamma \vDash \lnot \delta$? now i understand that it occurs because of the principle of explosion $(\forall a,b :(a \land \lnot a) \vdash b$.

my question is how to mathmatically write that

thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @BeginningMath Not fixed yet ... I would consistently use $\vDash$

Comment: For a proof see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2760199/what-is-the-proof-for-the-reductio-as-an-inferential-step/2760425#2760425

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because

$$\begin{array}\\
\gamma\\
\gamma\ \cup\{\delta\}\implies \lnot\ \gamma\\
\gamma\ \cup\{\delta\}\implies \gamma\\
\delta\\
\hline
\gamma\ \land \lnot\ \gamma
\end{array}$$

So $\delta$ has to be false, or you will arrive at a contradiction.

Comment: thank you so much for showing me the correct way to write that

Comment: What is $\lnot\gamma?$

Comment: @WilliamElliot: Whatever it is, the contradiction should not happen.

Answer (score 1):

$\Gamma\cup\{\delta\}\models\gamma$ means that statement $\gamma$ is always true in any evaluation that satisfies $\Gamma\cup\{\delta\}$, while $\Gamma\cup\{\delta\}\models\neg \gamma$ means that the statement $\gamma$ is never true in any evaluation that satisfies $\Gamma\cup\{\delta\}$.

This establishes that there can be no such evaluation that may satisfy both $\Gamma$ and $\{\delta\}$.

Hence *if there is* any evaluation which can satisfy the statements in $\Gamma$, that evaluation must deny $\delta$.

That is to say, $\Gamma\models\neg\delta$ is infered from $\Gamma\cup\{\delta\}\models\gamma$ and $\Gamma\cup\{\delta\}\models\neg\gamma$.

$$\begin{split}\Gamma\cup\{\delta\}&\models\gamma\\\Gamma\cup\{\delta\}&\models\neg\gamma\\\hline \Gamma&\models\neg \delta\end{split}$$